# CMake project Boost library error : boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, compiler-errors

I am developing **C++** code.
I am using **VisualStudio CMake project**.

I included my **Boost 1.66 version library** to my CMake project successfuly.

This is my **CMakeLists.txt** file :

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

project(CMakeProject4 CXX)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}'")

set(CROSS_COMPILER_DIR /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER_DIR}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER_DIR}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++) 

message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER='${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}'")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}'")

find_package(Boost 1.66.0 REQUIRED) 
add_executable (CMakeProject4 CMakeProject4.cpp CMakeProject4.h) 
target_link_libraries(CMakeProject4 PRIVATE Boost::headers)
```

When I save this file, I can see that :

```
1> /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="RelWithDebInfo" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_LIBRARIES:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH="/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteIL "/home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteCML/CMakeLists.txt";
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake'
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_C_COMPILER='/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc'
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++'
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1427 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1428 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "OFF"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1429 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1430 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1431 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1432 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1501 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1502 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1503 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1504 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1505 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1506 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1594 ] location of version.hpp: /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/version.hpp
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1634 ] Boost_VERSION = "106600"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1635 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.66.0"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1636 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "106600"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1637 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1638 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "66"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1639 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1640 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:766 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-gcc74" (guessed)
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = ""
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1771 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1775 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1776 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1836 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/lib;/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/../lib;/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
1> [CMake] -- [ /home/ubuntu/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1837 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/lib;/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/../lib;/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteBR
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> CMake generation finished.
```

I am going to use the `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++` compiler to compile my C++ program :

```
#include "CMakeProject4.h"
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::cout << "Type in any number: ";

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout
        << (boost::lambda::_1 * 10)
        << "\nType in another number: ");
}
```

But when I run the program, this error occurs :

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/CMakeProject4.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/type_traits/remove_reference.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/type_traits/add_pointer.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/type_traits/transform_traits.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/lambda/core.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:14,
                 from /home/ubuntu/CMake/RemoteCML/CMakeProject4/CMakeProject4.cpp:5:
/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/CMakeProject4.cpp.o' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:93: recipe for target 'CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: recipe for target 'CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'CMakeProject4' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/CMakeProject4.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeProject4/CMakeFiles/CMakeProject4.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [CMakeProject4] Error 2

Build failed.
```

Can anyone help me on that please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, yet it is too long for comment, so there.

I remember having this problem when cross-compiling (linux x86_64 to linux armhf), but I don't remember exactly what I did. I know that I followed more or less these steps:

1. Run cmake without building anything, only to configure things.
2. When running make (I assume you run it by hand), run:

```sh
VERBOSE=1 make
```

3. Copy exact executed line that failed, something like `g++ -I/.../ -pthread -o file.o -c file.cpp`
4. Enter build directory and execute this line adding `-v` option, so if line was as above, run:

```cpp
g++ -I/.../ -pthread -o file.o -c file.cpp -v
```

5. GCC will print, among others, information about include directories. In my case this is similar to this:

```sh
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/ZS/deps/include
 /home/jd/code/config/.
 /opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0
 /opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/backward
 /opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/ZS/deps/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Note, that in my output above (this is real output) there are two entries starting with `ignoring nonexistent directory`.

Check these nonexistent directories and also carefully check if there is file cstddef in any of those that are listed as existing (so probably after `#include <...> search starts here:`).

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: well .. maybe I did what you have mentioned in a bad way or maybe I was right .. but this not help

Comment: So I assume that there is header cstddef in paths show by gcc? I remember having field day with this bug, but it seems that solution was incredibly easy - though I really don't remember what it was. Sorry.